# Unable to access $rootScope in factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having a strange error with angular.js I am using version 1.2.26. Below is my code, I am not able to access properties I set in $rootScope. When I log $rootScope I can see those properties. But I am not able to access the properties.

```
angular
  .module('ids.factories', [])
  .factory('StoreFactory', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope);//This is defined and i can see the store property
    console.log($rootScope.store);//This seems to be undefined
    return {
      get: function (key, callback) {
        return $rootScope.store.get(key, callback)
      },
      save: function (key, data, callback) {
        $rootScope.store.save({
          key: key,
          value: data
        }, callback);
      },
      remove: function (key) {
        $rootScope.store.remove({key: key});
      }
    }
  }]);
```

[image]

Comment: can you set up plunk to reproduce error?

Comment: `console.log($rootScope.store);//This seems to be undefined` this run before you init `store` variable,isn,t it?

Comment: `console.log($rootScope)` will print a reference to `$rootScope`, which is why you can see the `store` property. It doesn't mean the `store` property was available at the actual execution of `console.log`, which is why it can be undefined in your second `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error depends on how the developer tools of your Browser are working. Like tasseKATT said in his [сomment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524097/unable-to-access-rootscope-in-factory#comment41677215_26524097), the console.log() got called before the Variable is initialized. Later in the Console, you see only a reference with the evaluated code. The Developer - Tool gives you a hint by a small blue Sign besides the console.log entry. (you see it in your screenshot, too)
Greetings!